# Replicar mensagem a todos os clientes de um chat

Tags: java, servidor, thread, socket, chat

Preciso replicar a mensagem de um cliente para todos que estiverem conectados, menos pro próprio cliente que enviou. Abaixo se encontra as classes que tenho até agora. Como poderia replicar essas mensagens?

```
public class Servidor {
  public static final int porta = 4444;
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Servidor().iniciarServidor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void iniciarServidor() throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
    System.out.println("Servidor esperando conexões..");
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        ThreadServidor st = new ThreadServidor(socket);
        st.start();
    }
}

}

public class Cliente {
private static Socket socket;
private Scanner scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    new Cliente().iniciarCliente();
}

public void iniciarCliente() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nome = scanner.nextLine();
    socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader bf = new java.io.BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true) {
        String leitura = bf.readLine();
        pw.println(nome + ": " + leitura);
    }
}

}

public class ThreadServidor extends Thread {
private Socket socket;
PrintWriter printWriter = null;

public ThreadServidor(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        String mensagem = null;
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        while ((mensagem = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Mensagem do cliente: " + mensagem);
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: O que está errado no código?

Comment: Nada, apenas não envia para todos os clientes conectados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa armazenar uma lista dos sockets dos clientes e criar uma rotina que itera sobre todos eles, escrevendo no `OutputStream` de cada um.

Outra alternativa seria criar no servidor *threads* de escrita além das *threads* de entrada.

Eu fiz [um exemplo completo de chat](https://github.com/utluiz/java-playground/tree/master/random-code/src/main/java/chat) usando a segunda técnica no qual você pode se basear.

As partes importantes estão a seguir.

A primeira é o mapa com as filas de mensagens a serem enviadas para cada cliente:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, BlockingDeque<Message>> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

A chave do mapa é o nome do usuário e cada valor é uma fila que armazena mensagens a serem enviadas para cada cliente.

A classe `BlockingDeque` é uma implementação especial de fila onde, caso ela esteja vazia, a thread que tenta ler um item da fila fica aguardando aparecer algum item.

Então, crio threads para cada cliente que ficam esperando as mensagens serem adicionadas nessa fila e, assim que chega alguma a thread escreve para o cliente.

O código da thread que envia as mensagens é este:

```
for (;;) {
    final Message message = outgoingMessagesToClient.take();
    ...
    outputStream.writeObject(message);
    outputStream.flush();
    ....
}
```

Para mandar uma mensagem para todos os usuários, basta adicionar a mensagem em todas as filas, assim:

```
private void sendMessageForAll(final Message message) {
    users.values().stream().forEach(q -> q.add(message));
}
```

Note que simplifiquei o código aqui para evitar detalhes mais complexos, como o caso onde há uma mensagem de saída do chat que encerra a conexão. Minha sugestão é implementar aos poucos e depois você começa a inserir mais detalhes,

Comment: Obrigado, muito útil!